# Multirow into table

Tags: tables, multirow

I have a table like this:
[image]

But in some cells of the columns "Prerequisiti" and "Tipologia" I need multirow (like in case of "Node Js | Apache").

I would like that che my cells looks like 
[image]
Is it possible?

This is my code

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c|c|c|c| } 
\hline
Framework & Linguaggio & Licenza & Prerequisiti & Tipologia \\
\hline
Pybossa & Python & Open Source & & Applicazioni Web \\ 
CrowdThruth & PHP & Open source & & Applicazioni Web\\ 
Ionic   & Angularjs & Open source & Node.js | Apache Cordova
& Native | Cross Platform\\
Appcelerator Titanium   & Javascript &  Open Source & Node.js |
Java & Cross platform \\
Xamarin & C\# & Open Source & Visual Studio & Native | Cross Platform \\
Django  & Python    & Open Source&  Python&     Applicazioni web\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

I use 
`\usepackage{multirow}`

but I don't know how to use it properly.

Comment: if possible also the cells equally high, but it's not fundamental.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the nicest (and in my opinion most underrated `:-)`) features of `tabular`s is that they can be nested. In this case, if the purpose is just to have some cells with a text written in more rows you can just define a command

```
\newcommand{\multlinecell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}
```

The `@{}` suppresses the spacing on the sides. You can then type your table as

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\newcommand{\multlinecell}[1]{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{6}{>{\vphantom{\multlinecell{two\\lines}}}c|}} 
\hline
\bfseries Framework \multlinecell{\strut\\\strut}& \bfseries Linguaggio & \bfseries Licenza & \bfseries Prerequisiti & \bfseries Tipologia \\
\hline
Pybossa & Python & Open Source & & Applicazioni Web \\ 
\hline
CrowdThruth & PHP & Open source & & Applicazioni Web\\ 
\hline
Ionic   & Angularjs & Open source & \multlinecell{Node.js\\Apache Cordova} & \multlinecell{Native\\Cross Platform}\\
\hline
\multlinecell{Appcelerator\\Titanium}   & Javascript &  Open Source & \multlinecell{Node.js\\Java} & Cross platform \\
\hline
Xamarin & C\# & Open Source & Visual Studio & \multlinecell{Native\\Cross Platform} \\
\hline
Django  & Python    & Open Source&  Python &  Applicazioni web \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I've used the `\multlinecell` also in order to force all cells to have the same height.

Answer (score 1):

with use of `makecell` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}% otherwise the text width is to small
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\normalsize}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
%---------------------------------------- for showing page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |*{5}{c|} }
\hline
\thead{Framework} & \thead{Linguaggio} & \thead{Licenza}
        & \thead{Prerequisiti}  & \thead{Tipologia}                \\
\hline
Pybossa & Python & Open Source  & & Applicazioni Web \\
\hline
CrowdThruth & PHP & Open source & & Applicazioni Web\\
\hline
Ionic   & Angularjs & Open source & \makecell{Node.js\\Apache Cordova} & \makecell{Native\\Cross Platform}\\
\hline
\makecell{Appcelerator\\Titanium}   & Javascript &  Open Source & \makecell{Node.js\\ Java} & Cross platform \\
\hline
Xamarin & C\# & Open Source & Visual Studio & \makecell{Native\\Cross Platform} \\
\hline
Django  & Python    & Open Source&  Python &  Applicazioni web \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on `makecell`, with some colour, and equal height rows (by trial and error):

```
\documentclass[svgnames, table]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array, makecell, booktabs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\mystrut{\rule[-2ex]{0pt}{24pt}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \sffamily\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
  \setcellgapes{5pt}\makegapedcells
  \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
  \arrayrulecolor{Gainsboro}
  \fbox{\begin{tabular}{ *{5}{c|}c}%{ |*{5}{c!{\color{Gainsboro}\vrule width0.4pt}}c}
      \thead{Framework} & \thead{Linguaggio} & \thead{Licenza} & \thead{Prerequisiti} & \thead{Tipologia} \\
      \Xhline{0.4pt}
      \mystrut Pybossa & Python & Open Source & & Applicazioni Web \\
      \hline
      \mystrut CrowdThruth & PHP & Open source & & Applicazioni Web \\
      \hline
      Ionic & Angularjs & Open source & \makecell{Node.js \\ Apache Cordova}
                           & \makecell{Native \\ Cross Platform}\\
      \hline
      \makecell{Appcelerator \\ Titanium} & Javascript & Open Source & \makecell{Node.js\\
      Java} & Cross platform \\
      \hline
      Xamarin & C\# & Open Source & Visual Studio & \makecell{Native \\Cross Platform} \\
      \hline
      \mystrut Django & Python & Open Source & Python & Applicazioni web \\\arrayrulecolor{black}
    \end{tabular}}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]